# Removing breaks from this output of Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is code to pull a product name and price from a specific URL:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/productdetails/84552/coca-cola-classic-soft-drink-multipack-cans')

time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

name = soup.find('h1', class_="shelfProductTile-title heading3").text
price = soup.find('div', class_="price price--large").text

print(name)
print(price)

header = ['name', 'price']
data = [name, price]

with open('Test.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(data)

driver.quit()

print("done")
```

And the output:

```
Coca-cola Classic Soft Drink Multipack Cans 375ml X30 Pack

$
24

.
90


done

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I remove all those line breaks, which are caused by the way the website separates the price into multiple classes, so I just get a result like

```
Coca-cola Classic Soft Drink Multipack Cans 375ml X30 Pack
$24.90
```

Comment: You can replace `.text` to `.get_text(strip=True)` But i recommend use [api page](https://www.woolworths.com.au/apis/ui/product/detail/84552) with JSON, you don't need to waste time while the page is loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```py
price = soup.find('div', class_="price price--large").text.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: better use `.get_text(strip=True)`